# R: Create a table from a list of data.frame objects

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I wish to create a table in RStudio that has the data.frame names as the rows, columns with categories defined by "xm...µm" and values for each row defined by "Sphericity.1": [source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsSlw.png)

Essentially, I wish to make a 51 x 100 table of Sphericity.1 values for each xm...µm category.

The source data is a list of 51 data.frame objects, each being a [100 x 2] list.
So far, I've only found solutions that bind all of the data.frame objects into one long list with 2 columns for "xm...µm" and "Sphericity.1". This is not what I want since "xm...µm" is the same for all data.frame objects (independent variable) and "Sphericity.1" is (dependent variable).

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need a pivot_wider after the normal bind

```
library(tidyverse)

(start <- list(
  data.frame(
    xm = 1:5,
    um = 5:1
  ),
  data.frame(
    xm = 6:10,
    um = 10:6
  )
))

bind_rows(start,.id="src") |> mutate(
  row=row_number()
) |> pivot_wider(names_from = "row",
                 values_from=c("xm","um"))
```